# JVM Loading duplicate libraries

Tags: java, jvm

If my Java application uses two JARS that each have the same version of a library, does the JVM only load the library once?

Comment: the JVM does not know what a library is. It just loads the classes on the classpath when needed and if there are two classes with the same canonical name it only loads the first it encounters, no mater if they differ or not. And as you might have already guessed - this can cause a lot of problems especially if you use third party libraries which depend on *different* versions of some other third party library. Luckily enough OSGi solves the problem :)

Comment: It is also a neet artifact of java that allows to shadow classes. It some times is the only bridge over troubled waters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two identical jar files with different name, then JVM will load classes from the first jar it finds, but in this case you will find no problems.

If you have two jars with different name, but they contain different versions of the same classes then you have a problem because you won't know which version of that classes will the JVM load first.

Comment: If you have a hard-dependency on a specific version and wish to avoid a conflict, consider class relocation so that your specific version has a different name than the other. For example, the maven-share plugin offers relocation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html

Comment: @Nicolas Barrera, what about when you have different applications using the same exact libraries/JARs in an application container like WebLogic.  For the same server, will the libraries be loaded be loaded twice?

Comment: @user994165 supposing you have two apps wich each one has *inside* (e.g.: app1/WEB-INF/lib in case of a webapp) then yes, classes in those libraries would be loaded twice. No problems would arise in case those libraries were the same but differ only in version as each app inside the container has his own classloader so each app would always load the correct version. 
If in your case libraries are the same version you could economize memory by installing that library as a container common lib, so apps class loaders would find the lib in it's parent class loader (the container's class loader).

Comment: @Nicholas Barrera, I suppose you would have to make sure the library supports that?  I read somewhere that this doesn't work for log4j as some state may be stored statically.

Comment: @user994165 as stated before it won't be a problem IF those are two different applications in the same container because each app uses it's own ClassLoader (inheriting from the container's ClassLoader). In regard to what you mention now, if that log4j library is loaded in the containers ClassPath and then you include it in one of the application's ClassPath there could be problemas of duplicate classes because of ClassLoader inheritance.